# What is the best/accepted way to charge multiple 18650 batteries in series but by themselves?

Tags: power

I am wondering if I had 4 18650 batteries that I want to run in series, is there a best/accepted way to charge each individual battery?  In other words, instead of having to purchase a 16V charger for all 4 batteries, can I connect an individual charging board (I have several left over from a previous project) to each battery without causing a problem with the output of the batteries being in series?

I realize this sounds like I am over complicating the situation, but I'm just trying to utilize what I have before having to buy something else.

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, no, it will not work. Each charger would be at a different ground potential, so they would have to be fully isolated from each-other. If you run them from a common ground that will not be the case. Current will flow and something will blow.

Hypothetically, yes this could be done if the circuit was designed *very* carefully.